# Is there a way to whitelist chromedriver process name while killing other processes?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First of all, I'd like to say this is a personal script and I am the only person who is ever going to run it.

I am writing a productivity program that blocks applications from running at a certain time, chrome is one of them. However, I do a lot of web scraping in a daily basis, so I need to 'whitelist' chromedriver from closing while the code is running.

This is how I'm using it:

```
import subprocess
imgNames = ["Chrome.exe"] # There are several processes on this list, not only chrome.
for img in imgNames:
     subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', img], shell=True)
```

Since chromedriver has the same .exe name, I'm thinking maybe there is a way of changing the process name or perhaps some other way of identifying it, so it stays open during the block sessions.

Comment: You might want to specify in the title that this is a Windows-only question. It would have a very different answer if you were trying to write something that worked on other platforms (you'd need to ditch `taskkill` use as a whole; I would generally suggest replacing it with the Python [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module).

Comment: ChromeDriver does NOT have the same process name... it's `chromedriver.exe` instead of `chrome.exe`.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Whenever I run a selenium script, there are two processes (chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe), however, my code kills the chrome.exe task and it closes my chromedriver browser with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt a strategy to exclude the list of *`whilelist_process`* from the entire list of *`total_processes`* as follows:

```
whilelist_process = "chromedriver.exe"
total_processes = ["Chrome.exe", ...] # There are several processes on this list, not only chrome.
kill_processes = [x for x in total_processes if x != whilelist_process]
for proc in kill_processes:
     subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', proc], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future facing the same problem: It's probably not the answer you were expecting, but I ended up using Firefox's geckodriver instead of chromedriver and now I'm able to kill the chromedriver and still have a selenium browser opened while the rest gets blocked.